# XAML c# get window location

Tags: position, window, location

How do programmers for XAML C# find the current position of a wpf application's window? there is a function to find the startup location but it's crucial that when the window is moved by dragging it to another side the position changes, so i always need the current position so that another function acts accordingly relative to the wpf window position.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about how to find window position but using cursor I have done it to find the current location, may be that can guide you. for knowing the current position of cursor you should be inside the window else it will always sho 0,0. Code is like this:

Xaml File:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Application 2" Height="350" Width="325"
        MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"
        AllowDrop="True" DragOver="Window_DragOver">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Name="lblInfo1" Content="Info 1"/>
        <Label Name="lblInfo2" Content="Info 2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C# file:

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)e.Source, "Sample", DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void Window_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Point p1 = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    lblInfo1.Content = string.Format("Mouse.GetPosition: {0}, {1}", p1.X, p1.Y);

    System.Windows.Point p2 = e.GetPosition(this);
    lblInfo2.Content = string.Format("DragEventArgs.GetPosition: {0}, {1}", p2.X, p2.Y);
}
```

Try it.

Comment: thanks for the input, i tried the code and i think we are almost to the solution, howabout you make the form button click to the form, then find the location of that click event, since the click was at the form-we can find the exact location of that form, for example: form1 launches, then clicks the middle of the form, then it grabs click location and outputs msgbox: this is location of your window, i hope this helps

Comment: Yes that can be done, as I guess your cursor will be inside the window and also dragging at the same time. What I think best for you would be make something in header as when you drag it and drop it, it will give the location exactly where it is.

Comment: Yea totally, im not sure where to start with the code though, i have never worked with mouseclick events... much help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For code-behind binding button with event:

```
private void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code...
}
```

Xaml file:

```
<Button Click="ButtonClicked">Button</Button>
```